# borel sigma algebra with a tensor product in superscript

Tags: measure-theory

What does a Borel sigma algebra with a tensor product sign in the superscript signify? e-g.,

Let $\{X_i : i\in \Bbb{N} \}$ be a stochastic process on $({\Bbb{R}}^{\Bbb{N}}, {\mathcal{B}}^{\otimes\Bbb{N}})$.

Also can someone recommend a book for a probabilistic understanding of measure theory.

Thanks,

Comment: It's the product borel algebra. Nothing to do with tensor.

Comment: You can for example see Chapter 14 of: Klenke, A. Probability Theory. A Comprehensive Course. Springer, 2013, which is titled: Probability Measures on Product Spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between $\otimes$ and $\times$ here is that $M\otimes N$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $M \times N=\{A\times B: A \in M, B\in N\}$, where $M,N$ are $\sigma$-algebras.

The superscript is just shorthand for multiple products.